# Dismissing MPMoviePlayerController as modal on rootviewcontroller iOS6

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm currently using a MPMoviePlayerController and adding it's view to an UIViewController which I'm presenting by using:

```
UIViewController *rootViewController = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];
[rootViewController presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

When I'm dismissing the modalviewcontroller by using:

```
UIViewController *rootViewController = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];
[rootViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Everything stays black.

This worked fine on iOS5. Another modalviewcontroller which isn't using a movieplayer still dismisses fine on iOS6 too.

I've tried the `[self.view.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` function, but that doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using presentViewController rather than presentModalViewController.  This works on iOS 5 and 6, whereas presentModalViewController is deprecated as of iOS 6.  It might not solve your problem completely, but it is better code practice.

Another thing: instead of using an MPMoviePlayerController and adding it to a view controller to display, why not use an MPMoviePlayerViewController?  All in one package.

If that *still* doesn't solve it, post up more data and you can be helped more easily.

Comment: The reason I've put it in another view was because the view needed to stay portrait, but the video could be in landscape. I've fix it by not adding the "go/exit fullscreen" observers in iOS6. The video in iOS6 still goes fullscreen, but does not play in portrait. Not completely what I wanted, but it will do.

Comment: Hm...well, note that if you present a view controller modally, you can determine what orientations it is in, independent of the orientation of the rest of the app.  For example, in iOS 6 this is done by `preferredInterfaceOrientationsForPresentation`, I believe.  To my knowledge, you could allow the video to rotate to portrait and landscape while keeping the rest of your app locked in portrait (which sounds like what you want, although it's not entirely clear).